# How to set custom permissions of an item with columns

Tags: infopath

I have a document library with a custom column that is associated with a check box in a form that I have. I want to set custom permissions if this check box is checked. Currently I can see the column in the document library and I can view the value indicating whether or not the check box is checked but I don't know how to change the permissions of the item that has the box checked automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Sharepoint Designer workflows for this.  In 2007, it required you to use a feature from codeplex to allow you to set item level permissions.  I haven't dug into 2010 long enough to see if they've included those actions.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually go about this is to hook in with an ItemUpdated event handler on either library or content type. Check the property value and set custom permission depending.

Couple of things that can blow up in your face here, so remember to disable event firing using EventFiringEnabled (new property in SP2010 if you did this in SP2007) if you need to update the item (or update will fire ItemUpdated etc and you will hit 51 recursions in no time;-)